# Display loading gif on every site loading and posting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have added two functions to my site master to show and hide my loading gif. But don't want to call it from ever ajax call or before post method.

Is the no jQuery for me to check if the site is loading and then call the show method. I notice during a post the tab that my site is on has a loader, how do they check when to show it and can i call my loader on the same method?

The big problem is my asp.net submit buttons sometimes take very long with complex functions and need a loader to be show.

Answer (score 1):

You can tap into global AJAX events to show/hide your loading gif on every AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
     // show loading gif
   },
   complete: function(){
     // hide loading gif
   }
 });
```

see: https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: Thanks that puts us half way there, that would make all the ajax posts work. However what can i do about the asp submit buttons?

Comment: I'm not sure. You'll have to see if ASP.NET has any nothing of pre/post AJAX events as well.